# Need to get text info into Explorer toolbar(via plugin xml)

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

This is probably a so simple thing that some of you will facepalm but here it goes anyway. I am working on a eclipse RCP project. I have to make a new Explorer which can be called from the context menus of items in other context menus. I need to get information about the item it was called from into the menu bar of the explorer. Alternatively a headline in the explorer with that info would also be okay. I can't seem to manage to put anything but commands into the menu contribution of the plugin xml. I have a refresh button in there that works fine, but how do I get text in there? I would be cool if it worked like the Type Hierarchy Explorer of Eclipse. There I can see a headline with the class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the top line of the view (like Type Hierarchy) by calling the

```
setContentDescription(String)
```

method of your `ViewPart`.

Comment: I did that, but sadly it does not show. I am making a Explorer, might that change things? I debuged into it and everything seems to be allright, but it just does not show up. The description on setContentDescription only talks about Views and Editors

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'making an Explorer'. Eclipse only has views and editors.

Comment: Hmm, well I guess it is a view. Could there be something set in a views DialogCore or somewhere else that would make setContentDescription not work? I debugged into it and it goes all the way, there is no reason why it should not be shown. Does something else except for the view part have an effect here

Answer (score 0):

Use http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/handlers/HandlerUtil.html#getCurrentSelection(org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent) or similar methods from HandlerUtil to extract active selection in your command handler. Then pass that info to your view.